# FFMpeg Invalid PNG signature when overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg in order to generate a video with an audio provided, a plain background (jpg), a logo (png, transparent background) and a video overlay (black background) between my background and my logo.
So the order is:
logo {on top of} overlay {on top of} background

So here is what I have now that works:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i overlay.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]format=gbrp [i]; [1]format=gbrp [v]; [i][v]blend=all_mode=screen[out]" -map [out] -map 2:a -y -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

In my ffmpeg command, image.jpg is my background + logo, which is not I want but I'm stuck here.
I have multiple "format=gbrp" because otherwise I have some pink overlay [such as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRlbb.jpg)

Here is what I  tried, blend overlay with my background, and put the png on top of this:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -loop 1 -i background.jpg -loop 1 -i logo.png -i overlay.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]format=gbrp [i]; [1]format=gbrp [p]; [2]format=gbrp [v]; [i][v]blend=all_mode=screen[ov]; [ov][p]overlay[out]" -map [out] -map 3:a -y -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

which gives me the following error:

```
[png @ 00000228db8331c0] Invalid PNG signature 0x8096C4E009AF6B98.
[...]
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Invalid data found when processing input-0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
```

Any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: Don't you have to repeat `-r 30 -loop 1` for the logo? I think that input options apply only to the input file that follows.

Comment: Yes you right! I just added a -loop 1 to my question, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the error, I still have "Error while decoding stream #1:0: Invalid data found when processing input"

Comment: I tried your command but could not reproduce the problem. Your PNG file may be corrupted/invalid. Just try `ffmpeg -r 30 -loop 1 -i logo.png foo.mp4` alone to eliminate other reasons.

Comment: My PNG was invalid, I tried your command and it gaves me the same error, but I can open it correctly... I have re-exported it and now it works perfecty. Thank you so much!!